# not all arguments converted during string formatting in FastAPI-Psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, fastapi

In my fastAPI project I'm trying to add new lines to a table in my database (postgres)

this is my table:

questions : 'question_id' of type integer, 'question' of type character varying.

this is my code

```
@router.post("/add-question", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def new_question(data: new_question):
    id = data.question_id
    #I try to verify if this id already exists.
    cursor.execute("""
    select * from questions where question_id = (%s)""", (str(id)),)
    value= cursor.fetchone()
    if value:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, detail=f"there is another question "
                                                                               f"with this id : {id}")
    # there isn't a question with this id, then I create it.

    cursor.execute("""
    insert into questions(question, question_id)
     values (%s,%s) returning *""", (data.question, data.question_id )
                   )
    conn.commit()

    return {
        "state": "your question has been added successfully"
    }
```

this is my schema :

```
class new_question(BaseModel):
    question:str
    question_id:int
```

the first 9 questions are added without any problems, but when I try to add a new question with the id 10 I get this errors :

> File "/Users/t/PycharmProjects/API/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2 >/extras.py", line 236, in execute
> return super().execute(query, vars)
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

**EDIT:**

here's how I send the request in Postman
(Http request : post /body: row, json)

```
{

    "question":  "If money was no object what would you buy?" ,
    "question_id": 10
}
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb No, I think I wrote it the same way the guy  did in the answer of this question

Comment: No `(str(id))` should be `(str(id),)` (note the position of the comma).  In your code, the question id is read as a sequence, so `10` becomes `(1, 0)` leading to the exception that you see.  Try it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb You are right, it's working now. But why the error occured when I passed value greater than 9, normally it should occure since the first try (id =1) ?

Comment: Because `str(id)` produces a string, which is a kind of sequence.  `cursor.execute` expects its values argument to be a sequence, so for 1-9 it gets a sequence of length 1 which matches the number of `%s` in the sql statement.  But `str(10)` results in a sequence of length 2, which doesn't match the number of `%s` so you get an error.  `(id,)` produces a tuple - a kind of sequence - with a single element, so no error. (So no need to call `str`).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Add it as a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values argument to `cursor.execute` should be `(id,)`.

`cursor.execute` expects its second argument to be a *sequence*<sup>*</sup>. Each element of the sequence is matched with an incidence of `%s` placeholder in `cursor.execute`'s first argument. If they don't match, an error is raised: an `IndexError` if there are too few values, a `TypeError` is there are too many.

Generally we think of sequences as being `list`s or `tuple`s, but a `str` is also a sequence, and this is what causes the confusing behaviour in the question.

`(str(id))` evaluates as a string, not a `tuple`, because there is no comma operator to construct a `tuple`.  For values 1 - 9, the values argument passed to `cursor.execute` is a `str` (sequence) of length 1, and this matches the placeholders in the SQL statement so the query works. However for value 10 we get a `str` of length 2, which doesn't match the number of placeholders and so we get a `TypeError`.

This is solved by passing the value as a single-element tuple `(id,)` so that the number of values and placeholders will always match. The call to `str` now serves no purpose and may be removed.

---

<sup>*</sup> Or a dictionary, but we aren't interested in that case here.